# How to delete an entire row from a data frame in Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

```
avg_ratings = ratings.groupby ('movieId').mean()

del avg_ratings = ('movieId')

avg_ratings.head()

File "<ipython-input-13-9ecfb8af04ef>", line 3
del avg_ratings = ('movieId')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you want to drop the index from the newly formed df? try `avg_ratings.values`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of row you want to delete, use [the drop() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), e. g:

```
rows_to_remove = [1, 2, 3]
df.drop(index=rows_to_remove, inplace=True)
```